# how to get the commit sha given a blob sha from the github REST api

Tags: git, rest, api, github, sha

if I have the sha for a blob in my github repository, can I use it to request the commit which it belongs to?

for example, [this markdown file](https://api.github.com/repos/dispersionlab/gitShow1/contents/score1.md) has a blob sha of `25931681beb665248c803d7337ef5150d037ed2c` -- is it possible to lookup the commit which contains this blob sha?

Comment: Just a remark : if you manage to reach a blob sha1 through the API, it will generally be because you actually know of some way to reach it. For example  : the link you provided points to a blob by its *filename in some commit* (file `score1.md` at the root dir of your repo), and you can see with the "url" link that the default ref is simply "master".

Comment: Otherwise : you probably have a local clone on your machine ...

Answer (score 3):

In the general case, there isn't a guarantee that only one commit with contain a particular blob.  If I add `foo.txt` in commit A, and then make commits B, C, and D without changing `foo.txt`, the same blob will be present as part of all those commits.

You can use `git describe` to describe a blob and find out *some* commit which contains it, but it may not be the one you're looking for.  The GitHub API doesn't provide this functionality because (a) there isn't always one right answer and (b) the operation can be quite expensive.